# getting page full URL in applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

A requirement is to get page url, basically I was in need to get ful URL of directory in which page is.

In case of www.domain.com/page.aspx I need www.domain.com/ and in case of www.domain.com/TestApplication1/Page.aspx I need www.domain.com/TestApplication1/

For this I tried:

```
Request.Url.DnsSafeHost.ToString()
```

Another code that I was using before that was building complete URL was:

```
Dim currenturl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
Dim url = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", currenturl.Scheme, currenturl.Host, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~" + Response.RedirectLocation))
```

BUT there was an issue, they do not work fine if page is inside an application.

For example, they work fine for www.domain.com/Page.aspx but do not work fine if page address is www.domain.com/TestApplication1/Page.aspx

I need in first case www.domain.com/ and in second example www.domain.com/TestApplication1/

Please guide how this can be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not fetch the URL and substring it from the last `/` symbol found in the string?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running this code from the context of the currently executing web application. If that is the case, then this should do the trick:

```
var pageSegments = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Split('/');

var pageFolder = "/" + string.Join("/", pageSegments.Take(pageSegments.Length - 1)) + "/";
```

So given a url of

```
/Test/SomeFolder/Test.aspx
```

You should get back

```
/Test/SomeFolder/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Request.Url.ToString());
string[] segments = uri.Segments;
string result = string.Format("{0}://{1}",uri.Scheme, uri.Host);
segments.ToList().ForEach(s =>
                             {
                                if(s!= segments[segments.Length-1])
                                     result += s;
                             });
```

You will find the expected result assigned to variable `result`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Dim pos As Integer = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/")
    Dim url As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, pos + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [HttpRequest.ServerVariables Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to access [IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx).  You can utilize that to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
string output = string.Empty;

    string httpHost = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
    string url = Request.ServerVariables["URL"];

    string[] splitUrl = url.Split('/');

    for (int i = 0; i < splitUrl.Length -1; i++)
    {
        if (splitUrl[i].Length > 0)
        {
            output += string.Format("/{0}", splitUrl[i]);
        }
    }

    string ssl = "http://";

    if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] == "off")
    {
        ssl = "https://";
    }

    output = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}/", ssl, httpHost, output);
```

Sample output:

```
http://localhost:60454/WebSite1/Folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Public Function GetAppUrl() As String
   Dim uri As Uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
   Dim baseUrl As String = uri.Scheme & "://" & uri.Authority
   If baseUrl.EndsWith("/") Then baseUrl = baseUrl.Substring(0, baseUrl.Length - 1)
   baseUrl &= HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
   If Not baseUrl.EndsWith("/") Then baseUrl &= "/"
   Return baseUrl
End Function
```